# Can i change a file located in a module under node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, unix, node-modules, stage

Is it possible for me to make changes in a file of a module under node_modules directory (by SSHing to that stage unix box) and expect the UI to reflect the changes just be restarting that app on that box? Without having to rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would work but I wouldn't recommend it, it would be better to fork the module and publish your own version of it to npm with the `npm publish` command and use your custom module instead. If it is a bug fix, do the above but issue a pull request while trying to honor the contribution guidelines.

That is unless you are using a bundling tool that minifies and compiles the js  modules to one file, in this case you would have to rebuild with the bundling tool you are using such as webpack, a grunt script etc.